# Calculator- how to store number after clicking an operator?

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I'm trying to build a calculator with vanilla javascript. I managed to store the first number and the operator, but I can't figure out how to store the second number. Can someone please give me a hint or tell mi if there's something wrong in the logic I've written so far?

These are the selectors and the variable where the numbers displayed are stored

```
const input = document.querySelector(".display");
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
const dot = document.querySelector(".dot");
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear");
let displayValue = "0";
```

These are the variables to store the numbers and the operator to use in the function

```
let firstNum = "";
let secondNum = "";
let operator;

function calculator(firstNum, secondNum, operator) {
    operators.forEach(operator => {
        operator.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            firstNum = displayValue;
            console.log(firstNum);
            operator = e.target.innerText;
            console.log(operator);
        })
    })
}


calculator();
```

I don't understand how to access the number after clicking the operator. Can I do it in the same  function?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="display">0</div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="clear">C</button>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <button class="number">7</button>
        <button class="number">8</button>
        <button class="number">9</button>
        <button class="operator">/</button>
        <button class="number">4</button>
        <button class="number">5</button>
        <button class="number">6</button>
        <button class="operator">x</button>
        <button class="number">1</button>
        <button class="number">2</button>
        <button class="number">3</button>
        <button class="operator">-</button>
        <button class="number">0</button>
        <button class="dot">.</button>
        <button class="operator">=</button>
        <button class="operator">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which number do you mean, the first or the second?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @WaisKamal the second

Comment: Do you want to make a calculator similar to windows? Where do you add a value, click the operator, click the second number and finally the equal sign?

Comment: @AksJacoves Yes, that's exactly it. I just want to display the first number and the second number, while storing both values and the operator. Later I will focus on the equal sign and the result

Comment: You said you were able to store the first number, to store the second you just create an array or use two variables as you are already doing 'firstNum and secondNum' and store the second value after the user clicks on an operator, that is, you need to create a checker to check if the user clicked on an operator and if he clicks on an operator this is when you will store that number in the variable 'secondNum'

Comment: I will create a small example using your html just to clarify for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a calculator that takes 2 numbers and an operator, then you could do the following to store the values for each number as well as the operator.

```
const input = document.querySelector(".display");
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
const dot = document.querySelector(".dot");
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear");
let displayValue = "0";

let firstNum = "";
let secondNum = "";
let operator = "";

numbers.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (operator === "") { // Read first number if no operator set yet
            firstNum += e.target.innerText;
            console.log(firstNum)
        } else { // Read second number
            secondNum += e.target.innerText;
            console.log(secondNum)
        }
    });
});

operators.forEach(op => {
    op.addEventListener("click", e => {
        operator = e.target.innerText;
        console.log(operator)
        // If equals operator, perform operation
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
To elaborate on the comment regarding the value of the first number not printing correctly to the console, please see the code snippet below:

```
numbers.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (operator === "") { // Read first number if no operator set yet
            firstNum += e.target.innerText;
        } else { // Read second number
            secondNum += e.target.innerText;
        }
    });
});

operators.forEach(op => {
    op.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.innerText !== "=") { // If the operator is not equals
            operator = e.target.innerText;

            console.log(firstNum); // Print the first number
            console.log(operator); // Print the operator

        } else { // If equals button clicked
            console.log(secondNum); // Print 2nd number

            switch (operator) { // Calculate and print output
                case "+":
                    console.log(parseInt(firstNum) + parseInt(secondNum));
                    break;

                case "-":
                    console.log(parseInt(firstNum) - parseInt(secondNum));
                    break;

                // etc...

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: There are a few catches to going about it this way, but hopefully it should give you an idea about how to go about implementing it for your case.

Comment: There's a problem if I want to use a number with more than one digit it returns multiple numbers. Let's say I type 25, it returns 2 and then 25.

Comment: This just how the numbers are logged, since they are logged for every click while the string value is being built, but the number that is stored in the end will be the full number that you want to calculate with.

For example, if you wanted to enter 25 + 5, you would click a number button twice (2 and 5)

I will edit my answer to better demonstrate this

Comment: In the updated snippet, you will see the first number when you click on an operator, then it will start reading into the second number, then once you press equals, it will print the second number and answer to the console, but this shouldn't be a problem if you're going to be displaying the updates in your html